# Add class attribute from generic annotation

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

I need to add attributes from a function but can't find a way for type hinting to support it.

The problem arises when trying to represent the return type using Protocol Union.

```py
from typing import Any, Protocol, TypeVar, Union


class JsonDictBase(Protocol): ...
class JsonDict(JsonDictBase, Protocol):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs: Any) -> None: ...
    key: str
    value: int
    other: Any


T = TypeVar('T', bound=JsonDictBase)


def build(cls: Union[T, type[JsonDictBase]]) -> Union[T, type[JsonDict]]:
    ...


@build
class MyClass:
    name: str

cls = MyClass  # type[MyClass] | type[JsonDict]

instance = MyClass(key='as')  # fails
```

What I expect the `build` function to do is add the JsonDict protocol attributes to the entered class. Without using inheritances

```py
@build
class MyClass:
    name: str


# So python understands this
class MyClass:
    name: str
    def __init__(self, **kwargs: Any) -> None: ...
    key: str
    value: int
    other: Any
```

Comment: i am not sure that i understand the question, but am interested in the answer....

Comment: Are you trying to achieve dynamically adding attributes and methods to a class through decorators? And also it seems like you want to generate code in runtime.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do here is to use `build` to create an intersection type of `MyClass` and `JsonDict`. An intersection type is the opposite of an union type. `Union[A, B]` means a type which is either `A` or `B`. `Intersection[A, B]` means a type which is `A` and `B`. Sadly python doesn't support intersection types yet - [It's worked on though](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213#issuecomment-1648409245).

Pyright does support intersection types internally - there's a workaround, but sadly it isn't possible with just that decorator. Other type checkers may support that pattern as well, I don't know about these though.

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, Any, Protocol, TypeVar

class JsonDictBase(Protocol): ...
class JsonDict(JsonDictBase, Protocol):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs: Any) -> None: ...
    key: str
    value: int
    other: Any

T = TypeVar('T', bound=type[JsonDictBase])

def build(cls: T) -> T: # note 'build' doesn't do anything regarding typing
    ...

@build
class MyClass:
    name: str

if TYPE_CHECKING: 
    # afaik there's no way to avoid this assert if you want an intersection
    assert issubclass(MyClass, JsonDict)


cls = MyClass  # type[<subclass of MyClass and JsonDict>]

instance = MyClass(key='as')  # succeeds
instance.name
instance.value
```

Note: As intersection types aren't a proper feature they sometimes behave kinda quirky. You may get false negatives and confusing error messages so be prepared.